# exception occurred while reading mail inbox from noreply.anyhost.com

Tags: java

I am running following code on my system it's working fine and i am able to get all unread mail from noreply.anyhost.com:

```
public void downloadEmailAttachments(String emailId) throws Exception
{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);

    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("mail.anyhost.com", "noreply@anyhost.com", "123354");//Exception occurred at this line only 

    Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);

    FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, true);//false for reading only unread message

    Message messages[] = folderInbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);

    for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Message message = messages[i];

        Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();

        Flags flags = message.getFlags();
        flags.getUserFlags();

        from = fromAddress[0].toString();

        Address[] replyAddress = message.getReplyTo();
        String replto=replyAddress[0].toString();

        subject = message.getSubject();
        sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

        contentType = message.getContentType();
    }
}
```

but whenever i am deploying this code class file on server system it's giving exception like below:

```
    Exception occurred.............

    javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused;
      nested exception is:
            java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
            at prg.util.PbMail.downloadFailedEmailInbox(PbMail.java:1813)
            at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:123)
            at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
            at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:84)
            at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
            at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
            ... 26 more
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check if the firewall on the server you're deployed to is setup to allow the connection.

Comment: Well, the exception says that the connection is refused. What else do you need to know?

Comment: The connection itself might be ok, but he might be using wrong authentication credentials. Check firewall, email server settings, username, password. And you have harcoded server settings in your merthod, which is , mildly said, wrong.